# Is there a word that describes something that wasn't made for how it's being used?

Tags: adjectives, attributive-nouns

In other words, what adjective could you use to describe something that is being used for a task it wasn't made for. An example might include using a plastic bottle of water to water a plant; yes it works, but using a watering can would make much more sense. A similar word/phrase example could be a "native application", which is a software program made work on a specific device platform like iOS.

Comment: I'm not sure that the software program is a particularly good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**repurpose**  / **repurposed**

**repurpose**

> To give a new purpose or use to
>
> *repurpose the company's website*
>
> *repurpose the archived material* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repurpose)

> Adapt for use in a different purpose.
>
> *They've taken a product that was originally designed for the CD-ROM
> and repurposed it for the Microsoft Network* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/repurpose)

---

> REPURPOSE
>
> One of the ways to reduce waste is to **repurpose** an item instead of
> throwing it away. “**Repurpose**” means to find another use!
>
> Keep your homework and other important papers organised in this
> **repurposed** cereal box.  [Lonely Planet Kids, A. Andrus; *101 Small Ways to Change the World*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/101_Small_Ways_to_Change_the_World/t9dwDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=water%20bottles%20repurposed%20as%20planters&pg=PT51&printsec=frontcover)